How to get object evaluation time?
I want to get the time in milliseconds spent evaluating a particular object. I wrote the basic code, but it seems to me that it does not work correctly. I have code that measures the execution time of modifiers, and the values of the sum of modifiers and evaluation vary quite a lot.
import bpy
import time

context = bpy.context
object = context.active_object

start_time = time.time()
object.update_tag()
context.view_layer.update()
obj = object.evaluated_get(context.view_layer.depsgraph)

times = time.time() - start_time

print(times*1000)

The evaluation time of the object's modifiers is about 6 ms, and the full evaluation time given by my script is 33 ms.The evaluated object is an element of the character's clothing, tied to the armature, and having several modifiers, such as Corrective Smooth and Lattice.


Hello, do you have only this object in your scene ? If not I think the value will be biased with context.view_layer.update() and any other evaluation that happens (UI, and everything else). I don't think there can be a reliable way to get what you're after, unless you mess with the source code.
